# Identity Core migration to Java

Tags: java, c#, .net-core

I have a Web API project made with .net core, I'm using IdentityCore for the user password sign up and log in. However, I need to migrate the API to Java. How can I do it without losing all my user data, is there any way to replicate the algorithm that IdentityCore uses?

Comment: please attach your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data are saved in a database when you are using .net core Identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1

So if you have correctly setup the IdentityCore authorization in your api, then there should be a connection string somewhere in your config like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database= IdentityDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

You can follow it, extract the tables and the data and you are set.

The source code can be found here: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity

The hashing algorithms: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-asp-net-core-identity-passwordhasher/

> ASP.NET Identity Version 2: PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations
>
> ASP.NET Core Identity Version 3: PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 10000 iterations

Comment: thanks a lot, I did know that I ended up finding the answer on the source code for the hash generation, that way at least I'll be able to replicate it

Comment: I added some more information on the hashing in the answer. Don't forget to upvote/accept useful answers. Cheers.